# set tint for uiview background color

Tags: iphone, uiview, colors, background, tint

how can i set tint color as a uiview background color?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`UIView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) view's `backgroundColor` property:

```
UIView *myView;
UIColor *myTint;
...
/* initialize myView and myTint */
...
myView.backgroundColor = myTint;
...
/* release myTint, if necessary */
```

Comment: toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; what i want is the same effect for uiview. btw toolbar is UIToolbar

Comment: A `UIView` does not have a `tintColor` property. Use `backgroundColor` just as you used `tintColor` for `toolbar`, or perhaps explain more clearly what you really want to do.

Comment: i want give gradiant background color for uiview.